# 3D Surface Plots Using Mayavi.mlab

Tags: python, mayavi

I have managed to plot multiple 2D histograms in a 3D environment, but I would like to plot them as a 3D surface. I have been trying to plot this by using mayavi.mlab's surf function with 3 1D arrays. But I get ZeroDivisionErrors  when I do this.

These are my arrays:

x = [-90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, -90.0, -80.0, -70.0, -60.0, -50.0, -40.0, -30.0, -20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0]

y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12]

z = [554, 310, 157, 97, 108, 169, 86, 64, 22, 20, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 424, 354, 165, 112, 156, 119, 55, 39, 19, 15, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 276, 455, 281, 176, 135, 98, 51, 30, 24, 17, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 263, 330, 283, 167, 90, 39, 30, 15, 7, 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 168, 259, 349, 283, 116, 42, 33, 13, 13, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44, 89, 124, 239, 384, 200, 77, 31, 19, 12, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 61, 97, 164, 441, 315, 82, 33, 12, 11, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 43, 106, 227, 402, 319, 94, 20, 14, 9, 16, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 91, 168, 269, 392, 224, 72, 34, 18, 9, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 179, 260, 361, 341, 168, 99, 54, 28, 18, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 215, 277, 245, 214, 181, 143, 128, 69, 44, 15, 12, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 427, 331, 207, 162, 120, 98, 127, 80, 43, 43, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Any help with my problem would be much appreciated!!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your arrays to be 2D:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(x).reshape((12, 18))
y = np.array(y).reshape((12, 18))
z = np.array(z).reshape((12, 18))
mlab.surf(x, y, z, ...)
```

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with 3D plots, but when I use the code you suggested nothing is plotted I just get a blank Mayavi scene. I there something else I have to add?

Comment: `mlab.show()`, if you are not set in interactive mode. See http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html